# Image drawing then blackscreen on AVD using cordova

Tags: android, javascript

I have an issue on my android JS based game, the game displays well for 1 second then total blackscreen.

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();

    (function() {
        var game = {
            canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'),
            frameWidth : 1280,
            frameHeight : 720
        };
        game.context = game.canvas.getContext('2d'),
        game.canvas.setAttribute('height', game.frameHeight);
        game.canvas.setAttribute('width', game.frameWidth);
        game.screens = {
            splash : new Image()
        }
        game.screens.splash.src = "src/img/splash.jpg";
        render(game);
    }());

    function render(game){
        game.context.drawImage(game.screens.splash, 0, 0, 1260, 720, 0, 0, 1260, 720);
        requestAnimFrame(function(){render(game)});
    }
```

The game works well on CocoonJS, I don't have any build error with Cordova. I tried to draw a rectangle instead of the image and it works.

I'm really sure it's a `drawImage()` issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer : the .jpg image was to hi-res, I just had to reduce it.

Comment: Can you elaborate about why?  It's not immediately obvious why that would cause your problem.

Comment: One of my images had a 2300*1600 resolution, i reduced his width to 900 (didn't need HD on mobile) and it worked !